# Consulta en SQL donde en una columna solo seleccione registros que tengan forzosamente dos registros en otra

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, subconsultas

Buen día comunidad.

Estoy con una consulta que en principio me parecía muy sencilla.

Mi tabla luce algo así

| No.Trazabilidad | Estación | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | EOL 1 ST 1 | Pass |
| 1111 | EOL 2 ST 2 | Pass |
| 1112 | EOL 1 ST 3 | Pass |
| 1113 | EOL 2 ST 4 | Pass |
| 1114 | EOL 1 ST 2 | Pass |
| 1115 | EOL 2 ST 4 | Fail |

Básicamente son dos equipos de prueba exactamente iguales con 15 estaciones. Se diferencían en el campo "Estación" ya sea que inicie con EOL 1 o EOL 2, pero el resto del campo corresponde al número de la estación.

Lo que necesito consultar, son los registros de trazabilidad que forzosamente hayan sido probados en los dos equipos. Una consulta con un "in" no me funciona porque me arroja si fueron probados en uno, en otro o en los dos.

Por cierto, en este sistema, cada número de trazabilidad recorre la línea completa. Es decir, cada número de trazabilidad ok tiene 15 registros al final como mínimo. Por ejemplo EOL 1 ST 1, EOL 1 ST 2, EOL 1 ST 3, etc, hasta llegar al 15.

Existe alguna manera de arrojar solo aquellos números de trazabilidad que forzosamente contengan por ejemplo en la columna estación "EOL 1 ST 4" y "EOL 2 ST 4", o sea que contenga los dos, no uno o el otro.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener aquellos números de trazabilidad que indicas en tu pregunta, es posible realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `No. Trazabilidad`
FROM [nombreTabla] t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  --Primera subconsulta
  SELECT *
  FROM [nombreTabla] t2
  WHERE t1.`No. Trazabilidad` = t2.`No. Trazabilidad`
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.Estacion, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) = 1
)
AND EXISTS (
  --Segunda subconsulta
  SELECT *
  FROM [nombreTabla] t3
  WHERE t1.`No. Trazabilidad` = t3.`No. Trazabilidad`
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t3.Estacion, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) = 2
)
```

Para que tengas un poco de perspectiva de que está sucediendo, la primera sub-consulta está seleccionando aquellos registros  que tengan números de trazabilidad tales que tengan como número de equipo "1", esto con ayuda de la clausula `WHERE` y la función `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. Y ya con estos resultados la segunda sub-consulta se encarga de realizar el mismo procedimiento pero con aquellos números de trazabilidad que tengan como número de equipo "2".

Por último, el `SELECT DISTINCT` del inicio se encuentra para eliminar resultados duplicados.

Espero que te sirva, en caso de algún problema puedes comentar la respuesta :)